# Sum of numbers appearing with unique values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this excel Sheet

| Date | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-1-23 | Gary | 5 |
| 10-1-23 | Phil | 6 |
| 11-1-23 | Adam | 4 |
| 11-1-23 | Gary | 2 |
| 12-1-23 | Adam | 3 |
| 15-1-23 | Phil | 6 |

For the purpose of finding the **total amounts** against Gary, Phil, Adam I am doing the following -

1. I'm sorting the names alphabetically.
2. Then I am manually counting each uisng a simple `=sum(num1+num2+...)` and deleting the extra rows.

I understand I can copy unique values somewhere in the sheet by going to the Data tab. I wonder if there is a easier way of capturing the sum of amount against the unique values in the form of **Name**.

The result should be something like

```
Gary 7
Phil 12
Adam 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with a [`SUMIF`-formula.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Assuming the names are in column B and the numbers in column C, enter something like this into the cell where you want the sum:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B7;"Gary";C2:C7)
```

Which should give you the result you want. In the attached screenshot you can see I put the name next to the sum and used that as the criteria instead, making it easier to copy the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PivotTable directly:

[image]